# Spring - Create bean based on Annotation field

Tags: spring

**UPDATE:** I used a different approach for my problem.

**Side-Question:** I would like to know how spring does it with the exclude in SpringBootApplication

The SpringBootApplication:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class))
public @interface SpringBootApplication {
```

So when the context is loaded, and the EnableAutoConfiguration is executed, the excludes are available.

Thats the same what i want.

At Bean-Creation i want to know if an Annotation has some field (for example boolean)

**Old Question:**

I have an Annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(TaskSpringContext.class)
public @interface TaskTest
{
    Class<? extends DatabaseService> db() default DatabaseService.class;
}
```

This Annotation is used at:

```
@TaskTest(db = DatabaseServiceExtended.class)
@SpringBootApplication()
public class TaskServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TaskServer.class, args);
    }

}
```

Now, at TaskSpringContext.class i want to create a bean based on the db-Field of the TaskTest-Annotation:

```
@Bean(name = "databaseService")
public DatabaseService databaseService()
{
    return ??
    Here i want to return the DatabaseServiceExtended
}
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: There is no guarantee that there is only one @SpringBootApplication on your classpath... So which one do you want? The one where your main method is? While there are ways to get the main class, none of them is pretty good, if you ask me. So perhaps you might want to look for alternatives, because I am quite positive that there's a better way to do what you want to do, based on the use case.

Comment: The SpringBootApplication Annotation has an field "exclude". There you can specify Classes. This classes must be read somehwere. Its the same what i want. I want to create a bean with an annotation and the field of the annotation should help creating the Bean.

Comment: It's not a good practice to edit your questions that much, but for the sake of clarity... Spring annotation mostly just create classes/beans. In this case, my answer below should help, since `@ComponentScan` (and it's older xml variant `<context:component-scan/>`)  basically use a variant of the `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` to find beans. The exclude simply adds an exclude filter to that object, so that some beans will not be considered. You can check out the whole thing at `org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there's a better way for it, but this will scan your classpath, starting from "com.example" for all classes annotated with `com.example.TaskTest` and add a bean definition for it, so that bean will be created later.

This will allow you to check all classes for your annotation, but of course you will have to solve the problem that two (or more) `@TaskTest` could be on your classpath.

```
@Component
public class TestBeanProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        ; // does nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        Set<BeanDefinition> definitions = scanForBeanDefinitionsIn("com.example"); // the base package

        // test if one or more, perhaps error, whatever

        BeanDefinition def = ...; // one of them

        Class<?> clz = Class.forName(def.getBeanClassName());
        TaskTest annotation = clz.getAnnotation(TaskTest.class);

        // create new RootBeanDefinition with TaskText Data (pretty analogous to XML)

        RootBeanDefinition dataSourceDefinition = ...;

        registry.registerBeanDefinition("dataSource", dataSourceDefinition);
    }

    protected Set<BeanDefinition> scanForBeanDefinitionsIn(String basePackage) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new TypeFilter() {

            @Override
            public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {
                return metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().getAnnotationTypes().contains("com.example.TaskTest");
            }

        });     
        return scanner.findCandidateComponents(basePackage);
    }
}
```