# spring bean interface definition

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to register interface and somehow to attach interface implementation to it through the bean definitions?
Simply I want to do this:

```
@Bean
public MyInterface myInterface(){
 return new MyInterfaceImpl();
}

interface MyInterface{
}
class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface{
}
```

but using BeanDefinitionRegistry in this way:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext applicationContext;

public void register() {
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
BeanDefinition myDefenition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .genericBeanDefinition(MyInterface.class)
        .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
        .getBeanDefinition();
registry.registerBeanDefinition("myInterface", myDefenition);
BeanDefinition myImplDefenition = BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .genericBeanDefinition(MyInterfaceImpl.class)
        .setScope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
        .getBeanDefinition();
registry.registerBeanDefinition("myImpl", myImplDefenition);        
}
```

Here I want some magic to force

```
applicationContext.getBeansOfType(MyInterface.class)
```

return `MyInterfaceImpl` beans.

I've browsed the documentation but haven't found something like this.
Is it possible or am I just wasting my time?

Comment: I've done something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107580/spring-create-bean-based-on-annotation-field/39116461#39116461 - just with a factory method instead of a simple class definition. Removing the whole factory part and replacing it with a simple `setTargetClass(MyInterfaceImpl.class);` should probably work.